# Difference between List<T> and List<object>?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Since everything inherits from object, what is the difference between `List<T>` and `List<object>`?  Advantages? Disadvantages?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you insert an `int` into `List<object>`, it will be boxed. If you insert it into `List<int>`, it will not be boxed (this is true for any value type, replacing `int` by the name of the type). Similarly for retrieving values from the `List<object>`, unboxing will occur, but not for `List<int>`.

`List<T>` is strongly typed, `List<object>` is not (so you lose compile-time safety, and can hit runtime blow ups).

Answer (score 12):

if you have `List<T>` you are sure that once the object is instantiated the list only contains instances of the T type, in a `List<object>` you can put anything inside.

Generics are a nice way to write reusable code having strong types at compile time anyway.

Comment: So, if the List can contain different types, is it better to use object?

Comment: Good answer by the way.  I did no think about type safety with List<T> as opposed to List<object>

Answer (score 5):

If you use `List<object>` you won't have any item typing and will have to cast everything. Plus, that's dangerous because you can put anything into the list and not know exactly what you're getting back for any given item.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the brackets, John. I was just heading to do that.

Comment: By "...item typing...", do you mean I won't be able to access properties or methods until I do a cast.

Comment: That plus compile time support that you are adding the correct type of item to the collection. The most obvious drawback, though, is not being able to interact with the object without casting, yes.

Answer (score 3):

List takes a generic type as the template argument.  So, you will genuinely have a list of cars if you do:

```
List<car> list = new List<car>();
```

Whereas:

```
List<object> objlist = new List<object>();
```

Can hold references to anything.  The problem is, these references are downcasted to objects and you can't use their members and functions until you recast them to the right object.  For example, if you held cars in objlist, you'd have to do:

```
((car)objlist[0]).GetMaker();
```

To call the cars GetMaker function wehreas with list you could do:

```
list[0].GetMaker();
```

This assumes you have at least one car/obj in the list.

Comment: Nice example. Helped me understand better.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider T as a type constraint on the List. So if you say

```
class Vehicle {} 
class Car : Vehicle {}
class Boat : Vehicle {}
class SpeedBoat : Boat {}
List<Boat> listOfBoats
```

The list can only contain a type of Boat and it's descendants but not any other Vehicles. If you had set it to object then the List could basically contain any reference type.

Note though that if you want e.g. all SpeedBoats from that collection you can use the nice extension method OfType:

```
//Returns IEnumerable<SpeedBoat>, casting is done for you
var speedBoats = listOfBoats.OfType<SpeedBoat>();
```

Comment: List<Vehicle> would allow me to use Car and Boat, correct? and since SpeedBoat inherits from Boat which inherits from Vehicle, would I just be able to do List<SpeedBoat> or do I have to use the OfType extension?

Comment: Yes a List(of Vehicles) can contain a Car, Boat, Speedboat, any descendants of Vehicle. List<SpeedBoat> would NOT allow e.g. .Add(new Boat()). If you want a List<SpeedBoat> out of a populated List<Vehicle> then you could say List<SpeedBoat> sbs = vehicles.OfType<SpeedBoat>()

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little confusing but I think jsmarble has hit on one of the main point in that you will have to cast everything to the type you require. The is inefficient, especially with value types which `List<T>` will handle without having to box and unbox the value.

You also sacrifice type safety which potentially could result in runtime errors.